# postgresql to sqlite migration issue

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, sqlite

I'm new to postgresql. I've django project using postgresql. I want to move my existing database in postgresql to sqlite. For this, I've tried different methods as mentioned in this forum but each gave me various errors. Finally, a tool named potgresql-to-sqlite worked with some minor changes to postgrql dump file. Now I could launch my django webapp. But on a certain page I get error like,

> TechItem' object has no attribute '_mi_selection_params_cache'

I've a column named 'mi_selection_params'., but there is no such column as '_mi_selection_params_cache' in my database.

What does this error mean? Where should I look into the code for solving this issue?

Here is the traceback,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\gir\python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 178, in __get__
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
AttributeError: 'TechItem' object has no attribute '_mi_selection_params_cache'
```

Here is the code from django related_discriptors.py

```
def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        """
        Get the related instance through the forward relation.

        With the example above, when getting ``child.parent``:

        - ``self`` is the descriptor managing the ``parent`` attribute
        - ``instance`` is the ``child`` instance
        - ``cls`` is the ``Child`` class (we don't need it)
        """
        if instance is None:
            return self

        # The related instance is loaded from the database and then cached in
        # the attribute defined in self.cache_name. It can also be pre-cached
        # by the reverse accessor (ReverseOneToOneDescriptor).
        try:
            rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
        except AttributeError:
            val = self.field.get_local_related_value(instance)
            if None in val:
                rel_obj = None
            else:
                rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
                # If this is a one-to-one relation, set the reverse accessor
                # cache on the related object to the current instance to avoid
                # an extra SQL query if it's accessed later on.
                if not self.field.remote_field.multiple:
                    setattr(rel_obj, self.field.remote_field.get_cache_name(), instance)
            setattr(instance, self.cache_name, rel_obj)

        if rel_obj is None and not self.field.null:
            raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
                "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.__name__, self.field.name)
            )
        else:
            return rel_obj
```

Comment: You could look at that code on that page. We can't see your code though, so we can't really tell you where to look. `_mi_selection_params_cache` doesn't sound like a postgres or sqlite thing, so it's most likely coming from your application. Furthermore that error sounds like a Python error, so maybe not even DB specific...?

Comment: Can you share the code from related_descriptors.py. Sounds like line 178 is where this is being thrown. I suspect that's a good place to start.

Comment: Is mi_selection_params a primary key column?

Comment: mi_selection_params is OneToOneField in TechItem

Comment: SQLite naming convention says "According to naming convention it is suggested to define primary key starting with underscore".

Comment: This should not cause any errors though. right?